# Problem with loading translation of JS file via ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript, i18n-l10n

I've got an ajax call that loads some info and a js file with something like Drupal.t('CLOSE HISTORY')

That string, although properly loaded in the database, does not get translated when loaded through ajax.

Are there any issues translating js files that are loaded through ajax?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Answer was simple - the js translation file that drupal generates was "stuck". Seems to have been a browser caching issue.